# Product quantity bound to colors and sizes table structures

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I've been thinking about how I'll be able to create products with sizes and colors which will match the max quantity of a product (or their total will be the max.quantity ).

Let's say I got a product which has a total 12 quantity.

In those 12 there are colors such as RED,BLUE,GREEN. AND there will be 3 sizes such as SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE

Like:

```
3x RED SMALL
1x RED LARGE

2x BLUE SMALL
2x BLUE MEDIUM
1x BLUE LARGE

1x GREEN SMALL
1x GREEN MEDIUM
1x GREEN LARGE
Total:12X
```

Now, sometimes some products wont have any colors, only sizes. Sometimes only colors, no sizes. Sometimes no color neither sizes.

What is the best way of structuring tables to acheive this?

I think like:

Products:
PID,name,(maxqty?)

Sizes:
SID, name

Colors:
CID,name

Used_sizes_colors:
PID,SID,CID,qty

How would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model you described looks good to me.

You can add a trigger that will work on UPDATE and INSERT and will check if `SUM(qty)` from `Used_sizes_colors` table for updated or inserted `PID` is greater than `Products.maxqty`, and if it is: rollback transaction and display error.